# Bokeh Tooltips get the Y-Value top

Tags: python, pandas, tooltip, bokeh

I have the following code, however at tooltips i want to display the y_value for each vbar.

```
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.transform import dodge

output_file("dodged_bars.html")

fruits = ['Apples', 'Pears', 'Nectarines', 'Plums', 'Grapes', 'Strawberries']
years = ['2015', '2016', '2017']

data = {'fruits' : fruits,
        '2015'   : [2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4],
        '2016'   : [5, 3, 3, 2, 4, 6],
        '2017'   : [3, 2, 4, 4, 5, 3]}

source = ColumnDataSource(data=data)

p = figure(x_range=fruits, y_range=(0, 10), plot_height=250, title="Fruit Counts by Year",
           toolbar_location=None, tools="", tooltips=[('Count', '$y_max')])

p.vbar(x=dodge('fruits', -0.25, range=p.x_range), top='2015', width=0.2, source=source,
       color="#c9d9d3", legend="2015 ")

p.vbar(x=dodge('fruits',  0.0,  range=p.x_range), top='2016', width=0.2, source=source,
       color="#718dbf", legend="2016 ")

p.vbar(x=dodge('fruits',  0.25, range=p.x_range), top='2017', width=0.2, source=source,
       color="#e84d60", legend="2017 ")

p.x_range.range_padding = 0.1
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.legend.location = "top_left"
p.legend.orientation = "horizontal"

show(p)
```

Is there a way to display the y_value for each vbar accordingly?
[Bokeh display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kaorg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do 2 things:

1. Add the `name` parameter to each of the `vbar` that has the same value as its `top`, like `name='2015'`
2. Replace `'$y_max'` with `'@$name'` in `tooltips`

Comment: Thankk you !! It works.. by the way can we set a variable to call the ColumnDataSource values? For instance now it's ```2015, 2016, 2017``` However, i want it like ```year1=2015, year2=2016, year3=2017``` because in the future I dont have to update each vbar if ```2018``` is there. Thanks !

Comment: You can use regular Python variables for the values, you don't have to use a ColumnDataSource for that.